# Why is navigateUp() going back 2 screens in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm starting to use jetpack compose navigation but I'm having an issue when I call navController.navigateUp(). For some reason its popping 2 screens instead of one.

Main -> List -> NewNote -> Call navController.navigateUp() -> List -> Main.

This is the navhost code:

```
val navController = rememberNavController()
            NavHost(
                navController = navController,
                startDestination = NoteScreen.MainScreen.route
            ) {
                composable(route = NoteScreen.MainScreen.route) {
                    MainScreen(navController)
                }
                composable(route = NoteScreen.ListScreen.route) {
                    ListScreen(navController)
                }
                composable(route = NoteScreen.DetailScreen.route + "/{${Constants.NOTE_ID}}") {
                    DetailScreen()
                }
                composable(route = NoteScreen.NewNoteScreen.route) {
                    NewNoteScreen(navController)
                }
            }
```

and here the code calling navigateUp()

```
val state by remember {
        newNoteViewModel.state
    }
if (state.finishUpload) {
        if (state.countFail == 0) {
            navController.navigateUp()
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

****EDIT****

For some reason that is called multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already found the solutions, the issue was that i called that as a check of the composable, and he is ran again on navigateUp. I need to call it as a launch effect.

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = state) {
        if (state.finishUpload && state.countFail == 0) {
            navController.navigateUp()
        }
    }
```